# Select a list of items that are mutually shared by two distinct values

Tags: mysql, node.js

Sorry I am quite new to mysql, so please bear with me.
Suppose I have

```
main     other
 A        1
 A        2
 B        3
 B        2
 C        4
 D        5
```

How should I query to return the `2` if I want to get the same item that is being shared by `A` and `B` under `main` ?

I tried `SELECT other FROM main WHERE main IN (A,B)` but it returns me all under `others`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a result set grouped by "other" with the corresponding set of "main", something like this should work.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT main) as main_set, other
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY other
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT main)='name1@gmail.com,name2@gmail.com';
```

You may keep or remove the `HAVING` clause for your need.

**UPDATE**: I am not familiar with node.js but if the query above is not working for you and you only need to return the shared value from the other column, below is another hack you can try

```
SELECT other 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE main IN ('name1@gmail.com','name2@gmail.com')
GROUP BY other
HAVING COUNT(other)>1;
```

[Results](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dwYj8vKRRYuurjJhhnLyEK/10)

Comment: However I realized it does not work if those A, B C D are in the format of name1@gmail.com, name2@gmail.com, and so on. They just returned empty array. How to fix that?

Comment: @tnkh I added a second approach. Let me know if that works for you. Also, I am not seeing any issue in terms of format of A,B,C.. in the fiddle.  Once you change the `create table` to say main varchar(32) which then allows for more characters, they should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are the tables called student/teachers or main/other? Anyway, I'm going to assume you're looking for all students where the teacher is 2.

`SELECT student FROM teachers WHERE teacher=2`

To ignore duplicates:

`SELECT DISTINCT student FROM teachers WHERE teacher=2`

Comment: Hi sorry I have made amendments. Pls check

Comment: It's the other way round that I wanted to query. I want to select 2 when A and B under `main` shared the same `2` from `others`.